# submit and cancel button on opposite sides

Tags: javascript, css

I believe this is just a css adjustment but I'm not sure.  I want my submit button (apply changes) button on the left and cancel button on the right.  Currently it is opposite.

This fiddle from a previous problem illustrates the issue (click the Edit button): http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/jdKxd/

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're creating the buttons dynamically can't you just create them in the opposite order, i.e., create the Cancel button before the Apply button? You've got them styled to `float:right`, so that should work.

(Or is the question about how to fix it purely with CSS?)

Comment: I did try that, but it didn't work. But I checked again to realize it was a caching issue.  Thanks.